# netbeans project loading issues

Tags: java, netbeans, vaadin, spring-tool-suite

I was trying to transfer one of my projects from NetBeans to STS. Is there any good (proven) way of doing that?For example, the problems is:

```
sept. 17, 2014 2:40:42 PM com.springsource.tcserver.security.PropertyDecoder <init>
Infos: tc Runtime property decoder using memory-based key
sept. 17, 2014 2:40:42 PM com.springsource.tcserver.security.PropertyDecoder <init>
Infos: tcServer Runtime property decoder has been initialized in 164 ms
sept. 17, 2014 2:40:42 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
Infos: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
sept. 17, 2014 2:40:42 PM com.springsource.tcserver.serviceability.rmi.JmxSocketListener init
Infos: Started up JMX registry on 127.0.0.1:6969 in 88 ms
sept. 17, 2014 2:40:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
Infos: Initialization processed in 577 ms
sept. 17, 2014 2:40:42 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
Infos: Démarrage du service Catalina
sept. 17, 2014 2:40:42 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
Infos: Starting Servlet Engine: VMware vFabric tc Runtime 2.9.6.RELEASE/7.0.53.B.RELEASE
sept. 17, 2014 2:40:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
Infos: Déploiement du descripteur de configuration C:\Users\Ashwath\Desktop\sts-bundle\vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.9.6.RELEASE\base-instance\conf\Catalina\localhost\Vaadin7.xml
sept. 17, 2014 2:40:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.SetContextPropertiesRule begin
Avertissement: [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Vaadin7' did not find a matching property.
sept. 17, 2014 2:40:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase addChildInternal
Grave: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Vaadin7]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:670)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1839)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The servlets named [com.example.vaadin7.Vaadin7UI$Servlet] and [main.java.com.insti7.vaadinproject.MyVaadinUI$Servlet] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/*] which is not permitted
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look like you have two "active" servlets which try to catch /* URI's

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The servlets named [com.example.vaadin7.Vaadin7UI$Servlet] and [main.java.com.insti7.vaadinproject.MyVaadinUI$Servlet] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/*] which is not permitted
```

You should probably remove the com.example.vaadin7.Vaadin7UI$Servlet servlet and then redeploy